# Auto re-size embedded video streams within DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vlc

I have a pretty simple application that displays four video streams in a quadrant.  The user is able to double click each video to activate full screen mode, and then again to revert back to the quadrant.  This all works great.

The problem I am encountering is determining the proper placement/size of the embedded objects within my DIVs.  Ideally I would like the videos to fully occupy each of the DIVs regardless of how the user may re-size their browser window.

My CSS looks like this:

```
.tl {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    background: white;
}
.tr {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 50%;
    background: white;
 }
.bl {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    background: white;
}
.br {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class='tr' id='vlc1'></div>
<div class='tl' id='vlc2'></div>
<div class='bl' id='vlc3'></div>
<div class='br' id='vlc4'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my javascript:

```
function play(instance, uri) {
    VLCobject.getInstance(instance).play(uri);
}

var player = null;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var mydiv = document.getElementById("tr");
    player = VLCobject.embedPlayer('vlc1', 400, 300, true);
    player.play("http://URL");
    player = VLCobject.embedPlayer('vlc2', 400, 300, true);
    player.play("http://URL");
    player = VLCobject.embedPlayer('vlc3', 400, 300, true);
    player.play("http://URL");
    player = VLCobject.embedPlayer('vlc4', 400, 300, true);
    player.play("http://URL");
});
```

I've created a jsfiddle of this here:  http://jsfiddle.net/AD4Vp/

I think that perhaps I need to dynamically alter the size of the embedded videos?  I understand that I am defining video sizes here (400,300) but the videos still are all left oriented in each div and I am not sure how I can determine what the 'optimal' initial size should be.

Any suggestions as to the best way to approach this would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came up with a solution and got rid of jquery-vlc.js

I updated my HTML and wrapped the videos in another container:

HTML:

```
<div class='tr'><div class="vlccontent" id='vlc1'></div></div>
<div class='tl'><div class="vlccontent" id='vlc2'></div></div>
<div class='bl'><div class="vlccontent" id='vlc3'></div></div>
<div class='br'><div class="vlccontent" id='vlc4'></div></div>
```

The CSS for this is:

```
.vlccontent {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   left: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}
```

In my javascript I then just used jquery to insert the embed statements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#vlc1').html('<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" toolbar="false" width="100%" height="100%" id="vlc_vid1" target="http://URL"></embed>');
    $('#vlc2').html('<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" toolbar="false" width="100%" height="100%" id="vlc_vid2" target="http://URL"></embed>');
    $('#vlc3').html('<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" toolbar="false" width="100%" height="100%" id="vlc_vid3" target="http://URL"></embed>');
    $('#vlc4').html('<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin" toolbar="false" width="100%" height="100%" id="vlc_vid4" target="http://URL"></embed>');
});
```

Works great now.